# Drools conditional element `not` firing RHS even if corresponding fact is present

Tags: drools

I have drools rule something like this

```
rule "some name"
when
  not Fact(
      field() == "something",
      group() in ("groupA", "groupB", "groupC"),
      isAllowed == true)
then
  // do something
end
```

I have following fact in the system

```
Fact{field=something, group=groupA, isAllowed=false)
Fact{field=something, group=groupB, isAllowed=false)
Fact{field=something, group=groupC, isAllowed=true)
```

Now my understanding about `not` conditional element is that `there must be none of matching fact in the working memory for rule to get trigger`. However, in my test, rules are getting trigger irrespective of whether there is a fact with `isAllowed` present in the working memory.

Is my understanding of `not` correct? If not, what would be the best way to model a rule which fires when there is no matching fact in the working memory?

Thank you!

Comment: How and when are you firing your rules? If you are firing them after every object is inserted, then you will see the rule firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `not` works, is that it won't trigger if the given fact matches all of the criteria. You indicate you have 3 facts which I'm going to label A, B, and C so I can reference them easier:

```
A: Fact{field=something, group=groupA, isAllowed=false)
B: Fact{field=something, group=groupB, isAllowed=false)
C: Fact{field=something, group=groupC, isAllowed=true)
```

Fact A does not match the pattern -- field and group conditions are satisfied, but isAllowed is not. Fact B also does not match the pattern for the same reason. Fact C *does* match the pattern -- field, group, and isAllowed conditions are all satisfied.

If you fire your rules with everything in working memory, it works as you'd expect:

```
rule "Example"
when
  not( Fact( field == "something", group in ("groupA", "groupB", "groupC"), isAllowed == true) )
then
  System.out.println("Rule fired");
end
```

```
KieSession session = ... // omitted for brevity
session.insert(new Fact("something", "groupA", false));
session.insert(new Fact("something", "groupB", false));
session.insert(new Fact("something", "groupC", true)); // *
session.fireAllRules();
```

... you will see that there is nothing printed as a result.

If you omit the final fact, where I've added the `// *` comment in the example above, you'll see the rule fire and the message get printed.

---

If you're seeing different behavior, you're doing something wrong. Either you're firing your rules without all the facts present, or your facts don't actually look like you think they do, or the way you're checking the data isn't correct.

But, as stated in your question, `not` works like you think it does. It triggers when there is no fact in working memory that matches the criteria declared.

Comment: You are right. Those facts were being inserted by another rule and I believe this rule was evaluating before the insertion and causing the RHS to be executed. Once, I added a check in LHS for fact load status to be completed, this started behaving as expected.